# How to draw random/irregular line in XAML canvas?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, win-universal-app

I have a canvas in XAML in which I want to draw random irregular (Hand drawn) line using C#.

This is what I want: http://jsfiddle.net/GfGVE/9/ HTML Canvas but in XAML C#

I want the line to be drawn Horizontally.

Xaml:

```
<Canvas Grid.Column="1" x:Name="ItemCanvas"></Canvas>
```

C#:

```
public ItemControl()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    canvas = this.ItemCanvas;    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add methods for the events `MouseMove`, `MouseDown`, `MouseEnter`, `MouseUp` and `MouseLeave`. Additionally you need two variables for the current position and the last position. If you also want to undo you need to add a `Stack<int>` for this. These are the needed methods:

```
private void Canvas_MouseDown(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    // push start of line onto undo stack
    this.undo.Push(this.paintCanvas.Children.Count);
    this.last = e.GetPosition(this.paintCanvas);
}

private void Canvas_MouseMove(Object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        if (this.last.X != -1)
        {
            Point current = e.GetPosition(this.paintCanvas);
            Line l = new Line();
            l.X1 = this.last.X;
            l.Y1 = this.last.Y;
            l.X2 = current.X;
            l.Y2 = current.Y;
            l.Stroke = this.brush;
            l.StrokeThickness = this.thickness;
            this.paintCanvas.Children.Add(l);
            this.last = current;
        }
    }
}

private void Canvas_MouseUp(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    // push end of line onto undo stack
    this.undo.Push(this.paintCanvas.Children.Count);
}

private void Canvas_MouseLeave(Object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    this.last = new Point(-1, -1);
}

private void Canvas_MouseEnter(Object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   this.last = e.GetPosition(this.paintCanvas);
}
```

To remove the last line from your canvas you can call this `Undo`-method:

```
private void Undo()
{
    if (this.undo.Count == 0)
        return;
    // pop indexes of last line (start index is one below top of stack)
    int to = this.undo.Pop();
    int from = this.undo.Pop();
    // remove last line from UIElement collection
    this.paintCanvas.Children.RemoveRange(from, to);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`InkCanvas`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.inkcanvas%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for this purpose. It defines an area that receives and displays ink strokes:

```
<Grid>
    <InkCanvas Name="InkCanvas1"></InkCanvas>
</Grid>
```

Result:

[image]